# Force 4-digit-year in localized strings generated from `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` in java.time

Tags: java, localization, java-time, 2-digit-year

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class in java.time offers three `ofLocalized…` methods for generating strings to represent values that include a year. For example, [`ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-).

```
Locale l = Locale.US ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( l );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) );
String output = today.format( f );
```

For the locales I have seen, the year is only two digits in the shorter [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) styles.

How to let java.time localize yet **force the years to be four digits** rather than two?

I suspect the Answer lies in [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class. But I cannot find any feature alter the length of year. I also perused the [Java 9 source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/client/jdk/file/b4776d6c9f76/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time), but cannot spelunk that code well enough to find an answer.

This Question is similar to:

- [forcing 4 digits year in java's simpledateformat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3108561/642706)
- [Jodatime: how to print 4-digit year?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17191575/642706)

…but those Questions are aimed at older date-time frameworks now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: The year has four digits in your example (with either `FormatStyle.FULL`, `FormatStyle.LONG` or `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`). What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @assylias The text of my Question refers to the shorter formats. I fixed the example code to match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no built-in method for what you want. However, you could apply following workaround:

```
Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
String shortPattern =
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        FormatStyle.SHORT,
        null,
        IsoChronology.INSTANCE,
        locale
    );
System.out.println(shortPattern); // M/d/yy
if (shortPattern.contains("yy") && !shortPattern.contains("yyy")) {
    shortPattern = shortPattern.replace("yy", "yyyy");
}
System.out.println(shortPattern); // M/d/yyyy

DateTimeFormatter shortStyleFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(shortPattern, locale);
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"));
String output = today.format(shortStyleFormatter);
System.out.println(output); // 11/29/2016
```