# Overwrite DateTimeFormatter localized date style parsing strategy for century

Tags: java, java-time, date-parsing, localdate

I need to parse the date string dynamically based on the locale and format style.

For example, I have an Albanian locale which has pattern **yy-MM-dd**

I have following code which resolves this pattern basing on the current locale and format style

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendLocalized(FormatStyle.SHORT, null)
                .toFormatter()
                .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("sq-AL"));
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest("92-07-09", LocalDateTime::from, LocalDate::from, LocalTime::from);
System.out.println(temporalAccessor);
```

The input string is parsed as **09/07/2092**

But I need to parse this date as **09/07/1992**

Adding the code for `.appendValueReduced` doesn't work

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendLocalized(FormatStyle.SHORT, null)
                .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 2, LocalDate.now().minusYears(80))
                .toFormatter()
                .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("sq-AL"));
```

I've searched for answers on StackOverflow but did not find any that works without `.appendPattern()` and based on the locale and format style

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813476/force-4-digit-year-in-localized-strings-generated-from-datetimeformatter-ofloca), you can first extract the pattern from the input string like so:

```
String shortPattern =
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
        FormatStyle.SHORT,
        null,
        IsoChronology.INSTANCE,
        Locale.forLanguageTag("sqi-AL")
    );
System.out.println(shortPattern); //y-MM-d
```

Now you can apply your formatter with specific year instructions. The pattern now is given explicitly with the `y`s removed since year is now being handled by `appendValueReduced`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(shortPattern.replaceAll("y","")))
                .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, LocalDate.now().minusYears(80))
                .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(shortPattern.replaceAll("y","")))
                .toFormatter();

TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest("92-07-09", LocalDate::from, LocalDateTime::from);
System.out.println(temporalAccessor); //1992-07-09
```

The reason for `appendOptional` is that if the locale pattern has year at the end, it could lead to parse error. For example, the pattern for the locale in your code(`sq-AL`) is actually `d.M.yy`. So we need to check for year at both ends.